# Inequality of continuous functions with integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

Let M be a positive real number.Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,M] $ be a continuous function satisfying
$$ \int\limits_{0}^\infty (1+x)f(x)dx<\infty.$$
Prove the following inequlity.
$$\left(
\int\limits_{0}^\infty f(x)dx 
\right)^2\le 4M\int\limits_{0}^\infty xf(x)dx.$$

Comment: Can you show in more detail what you did?

Comment: when f is continuous.can i consider this $??$
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (\int_{0}^t f(x)dx)^2=2f(t)(\int_{0}^t f(x)dx) $$
$$4M \frac{d}{dt} \int_{0}^txf(x)dx = 4Mtf(t) $$
and  obviously $$\int_{0}^t f(x)dx \le2Mt$$
and when in $t=0$ inequality holds ... for all $t$ inequality holds.

Comment: $f(x) \leq (1+x)f(x)$ and $xf(x)\leq (1+x)f(x)$ give their improper integral exist. We used the condition here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposal in the comments is close.  Try this:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \int_0^t f(x) dx \right)^2 = 2  \left( \int_0^t f(x) dx \right) \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(x) dx = 2 f(t) \int_0^t f(x) dx \\
\le 2 f(t) \int_0^t M dx = 2 M t f(t).
$$
Now integrate from $t=0$ to $t=T$:
$$
\left( \int_0^T f(x) dx \right)^2 \le \int_0^T 2 M tf(t) dt
$$
and then send $T \to \infty$ to get 
$$
\left( \int_0^\infty f(x) dx \right)^2 \le \int_0^\infty 2 M xf(x) dx.
$$

Comment: thank you for your good answer @Glitch. i have some question I would appreciated if you answered.
if $f$ continuous and $f:[a,b]\to R$ $f$ has a antiderivative but how about $f:R\to R$ $?$ and the other question, did you use the assumption that said $\int_{0}^\infty(1+x)f(x)dx < \infty$ $?$(in your last line can we always approach T to $\infty$?)

Comment: The function is assumed to be continuous, so it can be integrated on every compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$, and by assumption we know that $\int_0^\infty (1+x)f(x) dx < \infty$, so this means that both $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$ and $\int_0^\infty x f(x) dx$ are finite since $f \ge 0$.  I don't understand your last question, sorry.  I'm applying the limit as $T \to \infty$ to go from integrals over finite sets to integrals over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thanks again @Glitch. i understood all of my questions from your description.